# How to Add Local Nuget Package Source in Xamarin Studio on Mac?

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

We have our Local Nuget Setup which in on a Network path is like

//10.10.9.32/Microsoft/Nuget/

When I Configure New Source in Visual Studio. It configured correctly and working Fine

But When I am configuring Same Source on the Xamarin Studio on Mac. It is giving error Invalid Directory

How to come out from this error ?

Comment: If you ignore the error in Xamarin Studio preferences, can you use the package source in the Add Packages dialog?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this in the end? Same problem here

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The summary of a similar [question](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24415/cant-access-nuget-package-sources-on-an-smb-share) is:

It seems NuGet in Xamarin doesn't support SMB protocol. Try mounting the address `smb://10.10.9.32` and use a file URL (something like `file:///Volumes/Microsoft/Nuget/`) to configure the NuGet source.

Here is how you mount an SMB in Mac OS X: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/336665/how-to-automount-smb-shared-network-drives-in-mac-os-x-lion).

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here, but I think on OS X, connecting to file shares are different than in Windows.  Try connecting like this:

```
smb://10.10.9.32/Microsoft/Nuget/
```